# MinGW g++ producing (allegedly) 16 bit binary

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

Within MinGW, running g++ on:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
  cout<<"hi";
  return 0;
}
```

Happily creates a binary, but if I try to run the binary from the MinGW shell it complains of `Bad file number`and if I try to run it from Windows it complains that the binary is a 16 bit file. Is there a switch I should be passing to g++?

NB Fresh install of Msys and MinGW, cygwin was previously installed.

**Edit**

```
>> g++ --version
g++.exe (GCC) 4.8.1

>> g++ --target-help
... three screens worth of target options

>> g++ -print-search-dirs
 install: c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/
 programs:=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/mingw32/4.8.1/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/
 libraries: =c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/lib/mingw32/4.8.1/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../mingw32/4.8.1/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../;/mingw/lib/mingw32/4.8.1/;/mingw/lib/

>> g++ -print-libgcc-file-name 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/libgcc.a
```

Comment: How's g++ configured?

Comment: `--version` and `--target-help` command line options.

Comment: The `-v` option (not `--version`) tells you the target that GCC is built for.

Answer (score 4):

Ran into a similar issue that turned out to be a silly mistake: using -c option in addition to the -o option.  Assuming the code above is in main.cpp:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cpp -o test.exe
$ test.exe
sh: ./test.exe: Bad file number
```

Dropping the -c fixed the problem ( since that means "compile and assemble but don't link" )

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o test.exe
$ test.exe
hi
```

Comment: So you end up with a file that has an executable extension, but no PE signature (since it's not an executable file).  Windows treats a file that it has been asked to execute but doesn't have an executable signature as a 16-bit MS-DOS .com file.